# Writing a join in SQLAlchemy error: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is the first table I created

```
class Candidate(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'candidates'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  first = Column(String, nullable=False)
  last = Column(String)
  title = Column(String)
  company = Column(String, nullable=False)


  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Candidate(first='%s', last='%s', title = '%s', company='%s')>" % (self.first, self.last, self.title, self.company)

## Add user
morgan = Candidate(first='john', last='doe', title='some_title', company='some_company')
session.add(morgan)
session.commit()
```

I got this query to work:

```
morgan = session.query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.first=='morgan').first()
```

But when I add a second table, it stops working.

```
class Roles(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'role'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  role = Column(String, nullable=False)
  user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('candidates.id'))

  user = relationship("Candidate", back_populates="role")

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Roles(role='%s')>" % (self.role)
```

I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong with this:

```
Candidate.role = relationship("Roles", order_by=Roles.id, back_populates='user')
```

Try this search again

```
morgan = session.query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.first=='morgan').first()
```

And I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Mapper 'Mapper|Candidate|candidates' has no property 'role'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to SQLAlchemy but I think you need to update your join relationship under the role table to:

```
user = relationship("Candidate", back_populates="role", order_by=id).
```